# How to set a min height on a jqgrid which needs to have height: 'auto' so it can expand as needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, model-view-controller, jqgrid

In a .net6 web application, I have a jqgrid that currently height: 'auto'.

Some of the columns in the grid have a dropdown. The problem is that when there is only one row in the grid then values in the drop downs when expanded are not visible.

I would like the height of the grid to be set to a minimum of records even when there is one. If there are more than 3 records then the height should increase. The max number of records per page of the grid is 20.

The only challenge I am facing is setting the height to max(3,number of records).

I tried the following but it didnt work:

```
<text>
  $('#@item.CurrencyName').jqGrid({
    url: 'GetAcctInfoWithPermission?currencyID=@item.CurrencyID&clientID=@Model.ClientID&perResult=@Model.FeeGroupPermission',
    jsonReader: {
      root: 'rows',
      page: 'page',
      total: 'total',
      records: 'records',
      repeatitems: false,
      cell: 'cell',
      id: 'id',
      userdata: 'userdata'
    },
    datatype: 'json',
    sortname: 'Account',
    gridview: true,
    altRows: true,
    autowidth: true,
    height: function () {
    // Calculate the minimum height based on the minimum row count and row height
    var minGridHeight = 3 * $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'rowNum');
    var currentGridHeight = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');
    return Math.max(minGridHeight, currentGridHeight);,
    sortable: true,
    loadonce: false,
    pager: '#pager-@item.CurrencyID',
    pagerpos: 'right',
    recordpos: 'left',
    viewrecords: true,
    rowNum: 25,
    ....etc...
```

I tried also with the following but it doesnt seem that any value is being returned as a height :

```
height: function () {
        // Calculate the minimum height based on the minimum row count and row height
             If($(this).getGridParam("reccount") > 3)
            {return 'auto';} else {return 300;}
        },
```

Thank you

Comment: Which is the version of jqGrid used?

Comment: @TonyTomov its ~/lib/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.4/js/jquery.jqGrid.js

Comment: Unfortunately this is very old version and is no more supported. Could not provide solution. Actually the height parameter can not be a function and can not be changed like you do. This is statically parameter and to change it dynamically you will need to use a method like setGridHeight  in gridComplete event. Success.

Comment: @TonyTomov didnt seem to work, though its possible I implemented incorrectly. Another suggestion that did accomplish the goal was to set height: "auto" but insert empty records in the controller is their are less that three records.